# PostgreSQL logical replication - Copy of the initial data

Tags: database, postgresql, wal, logical-replication

I'm starting from a scenario where a PostgreSQL instance is not configured for logical replication and has a table T with X rows.
Now, when I'll enable the logical replication, create a replication_slot and a publication for the table T then every change on the table is published and can be consumed.
But what about the first X rows existing on the table T before the logical replication starts ?
How can I transform these rows in events that can be consumed by the subscribers ? Or how can I import these rows before the logical replication starts ?

Comment: If you use the built in pub/sub method for logical replication, it just works automatically.  If you are using something else, you need to say what it is.

Comment: Hi @jjanes thanks for your answe. 
 My doubt is ... how to get the snapshot content ? I've tried these steps : Create the table, insert 3 rows, Create the publication, create the replication slot -> no events are published on the replication slot. How can I manage this ?

Comment: You haven't addressed my comment, I still don't know what you are actually doing.  Show us the commands you actually run.

Comment: @jjanes ok. Here's the commands:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students (
          id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
          first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL
        );
INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth) VALUES ('a','b',now());
CREATE PUBLICATION students FOR ALL TABLES;
SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('slot_students', 'pgoutput');

With a typescript client I'm subscribing for changes on the slot_students replication slot but I'm not receiving the first row inserted (only after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using CREATE SUBSCRIPTION, then you will need to handle the initial snapshot for yourself.  Either query all the existing data, or start replication on an empty table and copy the existing data into that table from someplace else.

I think that using 'pgoutput' but not using CREATE SUBSCRIPTION is a bit suspect.  They were designed to work together.  There are other decoding plugins, maybe one of them would be better suited for being used by a "typescript client"?

Comment: excuse me but I'm not getting what have you said.
- *If you are not using CREATE SUBSCRIPTION* -> Wrong, I'm using it!
These are the commands that I'm using:
- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL );
- INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth) VALUES ('a','b',now()); 
- CREATE PUBLICATION students FOR ALL TABLES;
- SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('slot_students', 'pgoutput');
Please could you clarify your answer ?

Comment: You say you are using 'CREATE SUBSCRIPTION', but it doesn't appear in your list of commands.

Comment: sorry I'm not explaining well the situation. I'm using the cli commands just to create the publication and the replication slot.
Then I have my typescript client using this library [link](https://github.com/kibae/pg-logical-replication) and the method subscribe. 
When I start to consume the events I'm not getting the initial snapshot bu ONLY the new operation on the table. 
I'm trying to understand how to get the initial snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-architecture.html#LOGICAL-REPLICATION-SNAPSHOT

It takes a snapshot of the existing data at the beginning for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My doubt is ... how to get the snapshot content ? I've tried these steps : Create the table, insert 3 rows, Create the publication, create the replication slot -> no events are published on the replication slot. How can I manage this ?